# UISwitch in Table Row

Tags: uitableview, uiswitch

Basically I have a tableView like this:

[image: 1]

<strike>Now, I have an NSDictionary with the keys (title of cell) and objects (UISwitch.on).</strike>

I would like to make it so that when I click a switch, it should change the object's value accordingly (YES = ON, NO = OFF).

Different question, I've created the UISwitch so it has a function and the it's called when something's switched:

```
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void) switchChanged:(id)sender {
UISwitch* switchControl = sender;
NSLog( @"The switch is %@", switchControl.on ? @"ON" : @"OFF" );
}
```

Now I'd like to know, how can I tell in which row was it clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all who have this problem, I've found the solution by:

```
witchView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

This way, by the tag, you can identify in which row was the UISwitch changed.